# How to rotate objects in array along path

Tags: modeling, modifiers

When I apply the array modifier to the object, it follows the path "standing" up, I want the object to follow the curve "laying" down. The object is created in a "lying" down position. I have tried to rotate and change, but it's not working as I want. Is there a setting for this I have missed or how could this be done?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you rotate the object into the correct position? Also have you tried changing the follow axis in the *Curve* modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array modifier duplicates the object multiple times, the curve modifier can then control the direction of the duplications. The curve modifier uses the chosen axis of the object when it does the deform, the offset dimensions of the array modifier need to match the axis that the curve modifier is using.

[image: deform axis]

Each point in a curve has a tilt property. You can use this to align the objects second axis to point the direction you want. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to interactively alter the tilt in the viewport.

[image: curve tilt]